# What's the relation between tf.contrib.layers.feature_column and tf.feature_column?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-transform

They provide all most the same API.
Take embedding_column for example:

- tf.feature_column
  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/embedding_column
- tf.contrib.layers.feature_column
  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/embedding_column

Which one is preferred?

Besides, what's the relationship between feature column and tensor flow transform? They provide kind of similar functionality.